# ActionController::UrlGenerationError No route matches AND NoMethodError undefined method `accounts_lists_url' with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a Rails 4.2.beta1 application and I am trying to return the `:show` method after successful creation of a new object. The resource is nested in the following method:

```
resources :accounts do
    resources :lists do
end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {
    :account_id=>#<List id: 21, creator_id: 1, list_type_id: 1, 
                        name: "Test 16", description: nil, 
                        created_at: "2014-10-07 03:59:56", 
                        updated_at: "2014-10-07 03:59:56">, 
    :action=>"show", :controller=>"lists", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} 
    missing required keys: [:id]):

app/views/lists/show.json.jbuilder:2:in `_app_views_lists_show_json_jbuilder__4188070110312340824_70141816016640'
app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

What I see here is that rails is incorrectly thinking that the new `List` object is the `account_id`...

Here is my `create` action:

```
# POST /lists
# POST /lists.json
def create
  @list = List.new(creator: @account, list_type: ListType.find(list_params[:list_type_id]), name: list_params[:name])
  if @list.save
    @account.subscriptions << @list
    render action: :show, status: :created, location: [@account, @list] and return
  end
  render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

I found this Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629741/ruby-nomethoderror-undefined-method-blah-url-for-blahcontroller) and followed all of the answers there with no change in result. To list them out I have tried ALL of the following...

```
#1
render action: :show, status: :created, location: [@account, @list] and return

#2
render action: 'show', status: :created, location: [@account, @list] and return

#3
render action: :show, status: :created, location: [@list.creator, @list] and return

#4
render action: :show, status: :created, location: @list and return

#5
render action: :show, status: :created, location: [@list, @account] and return

#6
render action: :show, status: :created, location: [:account, @list] and return

#7
render action: :show, status: :created, location: accounts_list_url(@account, @list) and return

#8
render action: :show, status: :created and return

#9
redirect_to action: :show, status: :created, location: [@account, @list] and return

#10
redirect_to accounts_lists_url(@account, @list) and return
```

All of those produce the same error (or an obvious error like having the ids in the wrong order like in #5)

Another thing to note is that #7 && #10 produce the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `accounts_lists_url' for #<ListsController:0x007f9652235c40>)
```

Which also seems really strange to me

Comment: why do you want to render show action instead of redirecting?

Comment: You are missing an `end` keyword in your `routes.rb`, or is that a type?

Comment: @sebkomianos yeah that was poor copy/paste. There is actually another nested element within that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.... I feel like an idiot. I was reading the error message, but not actually ***reading*** the error message.

The issue was in my `show.json.jbuilder` file. I had an `account_list_url(@list)` call which was clearly incorrect. I thought I had checked there but apparently not.

Take home message: If the error message shows a stack trace with jbuilder in it. Look in the jbuilder file...